# Android app doesnt load previous firebase data

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application which is connected to the firebase. The app is sending requests to the firebase. And everything seems to work fine. However when requests stop coming for a while it feels like the app falls in a deep sleep and we have tough time starting it again afterwards. We can get into the app but previous files from database are not loading. The app is written in flutter that uses firestore as database.
We would really appreciate your thoughts, advises and solutions.

We didn't try much and what we are expecting is after the requests stop coming for a while, we were able to get into the app and load previous files from the database normally.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.